# PHP webdriver wait for Ajax to finish executing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Simply want to check that ajax is no longer executing, but there's not much in terms of documentation for this.

Closest answer I found is:
[phpwebdriver selenium wait for ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45597877/phpwebdriver-selenium-wait-for-ajax/48211708#48211708)

I tried to adapt the code in the answer below:

```
public function waitForAjaxComplete()
{

    $wait = new WebDriverWait($driver, 30);
    $wait->until(function(){
        $condition = 'arguments[0].call(null, $.active == 0)';
        if($driver->executeAsyncScript(array(
            'script' => $condition,
            'args' => array()
        ))
        )
            return true;
    }, 10000);
}
```

But it's returning the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String in vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Exception/WebDriverException.php:114
```

I tried variations of **$condition**, but it keeps returning the same thing. Sure others would find this solution useful as it would help determine when page containers finished reloading with new content via Ajax or simply to be able to confirm when javascript stopped executing on page using php webdriver

Comment: thats what WebDriverWaits are for.  Test for a condition that appears in the DOM after the ajax call is done: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing AJAX requests using jQuery, you can use this:

```php
$driver->wait()->until(
    function ($driver) {
        return $driver->executeScript('return jQuery.active === 0;');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Ondrej!

Comment: You're welcome! I also updated wiki on project github: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/How-to-work-with-AJAX-(jQuery,-Prototype,-Dojo)